# Gameobject that moves and spawns prefabs

Tags: c#, ios, unity-game-engine

I have a gameobject which moves forward and spawns a prefab every second or so. The only problems is that the spawning seems to be uneven and sometimes the objects are far apart and sometimes they overlap. I can sort of remedy this by changing the spawntime and distance but when i tested it on ios it broke again.

I tried creating a script which pushed the gameobject out of another object but it pushed it out and then the object hit and another object and when the other way.

What i want to be able to do it make the spawner move forward and place a prefab down so that the prefabs do not overlap. I need this to work on ios. I think it might be broken due to the

here is the spawn script:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class SpawnScript : MonoBehaviour {

    public GameObject[] obj;
    //public float spawnMin = 1;
    //public float spawnMax = 1;
    //public float spawnDistance = 0.1f;
    //private float barDisplay = 3; 
    public float timeLeft = 0.1f;  
    static bool finishTimer = false; //i made this global so you can access from other scripts 
    static bool timerStarted = false;

    //private GameObject GroundSpawner;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        timerStarted = true;

    }

    void Update(){
        Timer ();

        transform.Translate(Vector3.forward * 0.1f);


    }

    void Timer(){

        if (timerStarted == true) {         
            timeLeft -= Time.deltaTime;          
            if (timeLeft <= 0.0f) {        
                Spawn ();
                timerStarted = false;
            }
        }
    }

    void Spawn(){
        //GroundSpawner = GameObject.Find ("Ground Spawner");

        //if (GroundSpawner.transform.position) {
                    //Invoke ("Spawn", Random.Range (spawnMin, spawnMax));
                    Invoke ("Spawn", 1.75f);

                    Instantiate (obj [Random.Range (0, obj.Length)], transform.position, Quaternion.identity);

        //  }
    }
}
```

Here is the ground pushing out of another gameobject script:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class GroundHittingSelf : MonoBehaviour {

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

    }

    void OnCollisionEnter(Collision other) {
        Debug.Log("Hitting Ground without tag");
        if (other.gameObject.tag == "Ground") {
            //transform.position += new Vector3(0, 0, 0.1f);
            Debug.Log("Hitting Ground with tag");

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, couldn't understand exactly what you are trying to do. Can you post any image(screenshot) with your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The uneven spaces between instantiated prefabs come from the fact that your gameObject with `SpawnScript` is moving with changing speed.

This is because you are changing the position with `transform.Translate` within `Update` function without taking into account the deltatime. `Update` is called as many times in a second as the machine you are running your code on is able to call it. For example if the machine is doing some background work `Update` is called less often. In that case the gameObject will slow down. Or even worse, if the same code is run on different machine it will be lot faster/slower.

This can be fixed by taking the deltatime into account:

```
transform.Translate(Vector3.forward * Time.deltaTime * 3.0f);
```

Deltatime is usually quite small number so the constant needs to be set again. For example if you had nice speed with 30fps then 3.0f would be the one, because 3.0f * (1.0f / 30.0f) = 0.1f